# Can't write to file using fs on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10, fs

I have just downloaded LTS node (14.15.0 [npm 6.14.8]) on Windows 10 and I cannot write to file.

If I run the following script anywhere:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFileSync("./test.txt", "hello world", "utf-8");
```

I get the following error:

```
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Mehow\Documents\experiments\map-engine\data\moon\test.txt'] {
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'open',
path: C:\\path\\to\\my\\file\\test.txt
```

I've tried using the async method, I get the same error.

I've checked permissions on the folder, they look fine.

I've run the console as administrator, no change.

Oddly enough, I can make folders easily with a script like this:

```
fs.mkdirSync(some_directory, {recursive: true});
```

Anyone have any idea what else I can do?

Comment: Any chance someone else has that file open already?  Can you read that file from your node.js script?

Comment: Nope, it happens if I do it anywhere on disk, for entirely new files...

Comment: What permissions are you running your nodejs script with?  Perhaps try rebooting the system?  Why does the error message show `path: C:\\path\\to\\my\\file\\test.txt`?  Did you edit that?

Comment: I edited that, as it always points to the path where you run +  \test.txt. I've tried rebooting and I've tried repairing node

Comment: Well, it seems like it has to be some weird permissions thing unless its a bug in that specific version of nodejs.  With no ability to poke around in the system and look at things, I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below steps:-
1).Right Click . The Folder > Properties > Security Tab. Click on Edit to change Permissions > Select the user and give Full Control to that user
2).Uncheck the readonly option in the file properties